# Background image doesn't work, but I have the same code as someone who's is working

Tags: css

[Here's the SCSS style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0svg.png)

I'm following a tutorial on YouTube, and I have the same exact code the dude has, and yet for some reason mine doesn't work…

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "SF Pro", sans-serif;
    background-image: url("./img/paula-villena-kirchhartz-nDEAbWv_Zv4-unsplash.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
}

.app-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
    );
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to replace the image by actual text, and does that background file actually exist on your setup?

Comment: @KenY-N Yes it does. It's in the directory the URL is trying to get it from.

Comment: https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1455185376876826625/s1AjSxph_400x400.jpg Try this image url. If this works, it means you have incorrect path to your image

Comment: @MitulMandaliya It's not working either...

Comment: Can you share the tutorial you are following?

Comment: @MitulMandaliya Here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4dtwWgRueI&ab_channel=TylerPotts He's using CSS, and I'm using SCSS, but that shouldn't be the problem I think, since it compiles the file into a CSS

Comment: Maybe the path of image is wrong

Comment: Please include [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case, without assessing the HTML markup it's impossible to provide any insights. Your stylesheet in itself doesn't seem to contain any error.

Comment: Can you try to put two dots in front of your image path? `url("../img/paula-villena-kirchhartz-nDEAbWv_Zv4-unsplash.jpg")` If that doesn't work, please share your folder structure, to make sure it's not a path problem.

Comment: @DvdRom I even tried putting the picture in the same folder the as the CSS, but it's not working either. Here are my folders and the code: https://cln.sh/xw8a0b

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and put your HTML and CSS into your question - currently people are working with insufficient information to give you an answer that isn't basically a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and raised a codepen for reproducing the issue. It looks your URI is incorrect, because I just changed by another image from Unsplash and it works fine:

Removed line:

```
    background-image: url("./img/paula-villena-kirchhartz-nDEAbWv_Zv4-unsplash.jpg");
```

New line:

```
background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1646295671908-e296e79a001c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2340&q=80");
```

Please, if this [demo](https://codepen.io/maremarismaria/pen/dyZazVN) does not fix your issue, let me know and we will see what we can do.

Cheers!